# Group questions by answers with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server table:

| userId | QuestionId | Question | AnswerId | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 380 | 4000 |
| 32 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 385 | 5 |
| 33 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 382 | 3000 |
| 33 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 385 | 5 |
| 34 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 382 | 3000 |
| 34 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 385 | 5 |
| 35 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 381 | 5000 |
| 35 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 384 | 4 |
| 36 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 381 | 5000 |
| 36 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 383 | 3 |
| 37 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 381 | 5000 |
| 37 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 383 | 3 |
| 38 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 380 | 4000 |
| 38 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 385 | 5 |
| 39 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 380 | 4000 |
| 39 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 385 | 5 |
| 41 | 98 | What is the total salary in your family? | 381 | 5000 |
| 41 | 99 | How many are brothers? | 383 | 3 |

I want to find the list of the number of common answers given to the questions

Example:

salary: 5000 brothers: 3 count =  3 user

| Question1Id | Question2Id | Answer1 | Answer2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98 | 99 | 3000 | 5 | 2 |
| 98 | 99 | 4000 | 5 | 3 |
| 98 | 99 | 5000 | 3 | 3 |
| 98 | 99 | 5000 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: Please tag correctly.  SQL Server <> Postgres.  Which are you using?  Also, what have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @squillman sql type doesn't matter. but mssql is my first choice.

Comment: It matters because the solutions are potentially different between platforms.

Comment: I fixed the tags.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your SQL query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself.  And explain in what way the result you're getting is not what you expect.

Comment: The SQL language has a very strict requirement to know the number and type for columns at query compile time, _before looking at any data_. If you have to look at data to get column info for things like `Answer1, Answer2, ... AnswerN`, you're gonna need to use dynamic SQL, and really you're better off pivoting the data in the client language or reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select
  a.questionid, b.questionid,
  a.answer as answer1, b.answer as answer2, count(*) as count
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.userid = b.userid
where a.questionid = 98
  and b.questionid = 99
group by a.questionid, b.questionid, a.answer, b.answer
```